# Decrement the variable

Tags: python, increment, decrement

Struggling to wrap my head around this one. The `score` variable is incrementing fine, but it is not decrementing how it should be.

If I take the `score` variable out of the while loop and put it in the function then it decrements as it should, but it increments the value by adding the total number of "correct guesses" together. So if they have a_a_a_ correct, then the next "score" will add +40 (number of chars already guess + the new guess).

Then having it where it is (inside the while loop), it is incrementing the var as it should be (+10 for every correct guess), but it does not decrement the var at all.

I have tried all sorts, any help would be appreciated?

```
def game():
    word = random.choice(space).strip()
    random_word = ""
    attempts = 10

    print("\n*** Number of letters in word ***:", len(word))
    time.sleep(1)

    while attempts > 0:
        fail_count = 0
        score = 0

        for guess_char in word:
            if guess_char in random_word:
                print(guess_char, end=" ")
                score += 10
            else:
                print("_", end=" ")
                fail_count += 1

        print("\nCurrent Score:", score)

        if fail_count == 0:
            print("\nWell done! You're a winner!! \nResult:", word.title())
            time.sleep(1.0)
            print("\nYour final Score: ", score)  # print the score
            time.sleep(1.0)

            user_input = input("\nWould you like to play again for the high score? ")
            if user_input == "Y" or user_input == "y":
                game()
            elif user_input == "N" or user_input == "n":
                print("Thank you for playing!")
                time.sleep(1.0)
                print("Exiting Game")
                time.sleep(1.0)
                exit()

        guess_letter = input("\nGuess a letter: ")
        random_word += guess_letter

        if guess_letter not in word:
            attempts -= 1
            score -= 5
            print("Incorrect \nYou have", + attempts, "attempts left")
```

For the record, I am currently learning at University, only been doing it a month or so, so if my code isn't "clean" then forgive me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `word` is what you want the player to guess one letter at a time.

You need to move the `fail_count` and `score` to outside the loop. They are being reset on each iteration otherwise.

This block is running on every guess which is why you are seeing weird score increment behavior. Once you guess a letter right, you get credit for that guess on every iteration.

```
for guess_char in word:
  if guess_char in random_word:
    score += 10
    fail_count += 1
```

By having this block at the bottom of your code you guarantee a failure on the first iteration.

```
guess_letter = input("\nGuess a letter: ")
```

I've updated the code to fix those issues and some other issues like the recursion. I've left out the pieces strictly related to player output for brevity.

```
def game():
  word = random.choice(space).strip()
  random_word = ""
  attempts = 10
  already_guessed = set()

  fail_count = 0
  score = 0

  for _ in range(attempts): # removes the manual decrement.
    while True:
      guess_letter = input("\nGuess a letter: ")
      if guess_letter not in already_guessed:
        break
      else:
        print('Already guessed')
    already_guessed.add(guess_letter)

    if guess_letter not in word:
        score -= 5
    else:
        fail_count += 1

    if fail_count == 0:
        user_input = input("play again?")
        if user_input.lower() == "y":
            return True
        return False

while True: # This block removes the recursion.
  cont = game()
  if not cont:
     print('bye')
```

Comment: Appreciate the time and effort there. The code works exactly as it should. I need the game to print "_" where the guess is not correct, and the letter where the guess is correct. The code you altered doesn't allow this. Although it looks cleaner, the entire game doesn't work when implementing your version, it asks for a guess, but ends the game after one guess. My version doesn't fail anywhere, all it is doing is incrementing the score exactly how it should be, but not decrementing at all. I will have a proper look in the morning and double check I'm doing everything you said correctly.

Comment: To print outputs on success/fail guesses you just need to add a print to the "if guess_letter not in word:" block and its else block. The reason my version fails immediately is the "if fail_count == 0" block. I didn't quite get what you were trying to do so I just left it alone. It isn't clear why you have a fail_count and a fixed number of attempts. I'm happy to tweak the code if you can clarify what you want the code to do.

Comment: I spent a few days figuring out how to chop that code in half and still get it to function, but everything I tried gave me the same result; it stops functioning before you get to enter a letter, so I stuck with what worked. The fail_count determines whether the letters in the word have been found. For every wrong char, the attempts go down (max 10, otherwise they could guess forever), the fail_count goes up. As long as the user doesn't fail (run out of attempts), they win. I hope that helps? I am trying to do this with as little help as possible, but the variable decrement was driving me nuts.